# how to get data from json in c#?

Tags: c#, json

I Get json data from third party in json format.
 I am trying to fetch  `RollId` from "Id" and `MType` from  "Data" in some cases 
"Data" doesn't have fields it is kind of blank.

It's working when we have "Data". In case of blank it's not working.
any idea on this? Is there a better approach of doing this?

This is the Json

```
      string json = @"{
  'root': {
    '_type': '_container',
    'Class': '.key.PModel',
    'Elements': {
      '_type': 'array<element>',
      '_data': [
        {
          '_type': 'element',
          'Class': '.key.PElement',
          'Id': {
            '_type': 'testId',
            'Class': '.key.PModel',
            'RollId': '.key.7157'
          },
          'Data': {
            '_type': 'p_model',
            'Class': '.key.Unsupported',
            'MType': '.TestMType',
            'Version': {
              '_type': 'test__version',
              'Class': '.key.TestVersion',

            }
          }
        },
        {
          '_type': 'element',
          'Class': '.key.PElement',
          'Id': {
            '_type': 'TestId',
            'Class': '.key.PModel',
            'RollId': '.key.11261'
          },
          'Data': '.ref.root.Elements.0.Data'
        },
        {
          '_type': 'element',
          'Class': '.key.PElement',
          'Id': {
            '_type': 'TestId',
            'Class': '.key.PModel',
            'RollId': '.key.7914'
          },
          'Data': '.ref.root.Elements.0.Data'
        }

      ]
    }
  }
}";
```

This is the Code

```
public class Program
        {
            static void Main(string[] args)
            {
                //it provide json  
                var testCont = thirdpartyapi();
                var dataList = new List<TestResponse>();
                foreach (var testData in testCont.Elements())
                {
                    var data = new TestResponse();
                    data.col1 = Convert.ToInt32(testData.Id().RollId());
                    data.col2 = testData.Data().MType().ToString();
                    dataList.Add(data);
                }

            }


            public class TestResponse
            {
                public int col1 { get; set; }
                public string col2 { get; set; }


            }
        }
```

Comment: This JSON is invalid.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to convert Json string to c# Class object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30005332/how-to-convert-json-string-to-c-sharp-class-object)

Comment: @Adriani6 .. Sorry, just added the json string.

Comment: @Harshit the code you posted doesn't show what you tried. What is `thirdpartyapi` and `Elements`? Are you using a specific deserializer or is this a question about **querying** JSON data?

Answer (score 0):

First, try to get a valid well-formed json. You can use this [code beautify tool](https://codebeautify.org/jsonviewer). Then you can automatically generate C# class using [json2csharp](http://json2csharp.com/). Finally as you have C# class you can apply if statements and check if property is null.

Generated C# wrapper:

```
public class Id
{
    public string _type { get; set; }
    public string Class { get; set; }
    public string RollId { get; set; }
}

public class Datum
{
    public string _type { get; set; }
    public string Class { get; set; }
    public Id Id { get; set; }
    public object Data { get; set; }
}

public class Elements
{
    public string _type { get; set; }
    public List<Datum> _data { get; set; }
}

public class Root
{
    public string _type { get; set; }
    public string Class { get; set; }
    public Elements Elements { get; set; }
}

public class RootObject
{
    public int encoding_version { get; set; }
    public Root root { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! but i am trying to fetch 'RollId' and 'MType' from "Data" can we pick only these two fields?

Comment: You can actually paste the json straight into classes using built-in "Paste As Special" tool in Visual Studio.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to pick only few fields from complex JSON, you can consider using [Cinchoo ETL](https://www.nuget.org/packages/ChoETL.JSON/) - an open source library

Sample below shows how to pick `RollId` and `MType` values from your json

```
using (var r = new ChoJSONReader("## YOUR JSON FILE PATH ##")
    .WithJSONPath("$.._data")
    .WithField("RollId", jsonPath: "$..Id.RollId", fieldType: typeof(string))
    .WithField("MType", jsonPath: "$..Data.MType", fieldType: typeof(string))
    )

{
    foreach (var rec in r)
    {
        Console.WriteLine((string)rec.RollId);
        Console.WriteLine((string)rec.MType);
    }
}
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score -1):

The easiest way is use the `DataContractJsonSerializer`

[Here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/feature-details/how-to-serialize-and-deserialize-json-data) you can read more about it.

All in all you need to create a model which has the same possible outcome as your json. 
Then you can just use the `DataContractJsonSerializer` to create an object of you model by using a `MemoryStream`.

[Here](http://json2csharp.com/) you can find a nice tool to create the model from the JSON.
For example this one:

```
public class Id
{
    public string _type { get; set; }
    public string Class { get; set; }
    public string RollId { get; set; }
}

public class Datum
{
    public string _type { get; set; }
    public string Class { get; set; }
    public Id Id { get; set; }
    public object Data { get; set; }
}

public class Elements
{
    public string _type { get; set; }
    public List<Datum> _data { get; set; }
}

public class Root
{
    public string _type { get; set; }
    public string Class { get; set; }
    public Elements Elements { get; set; }
}

public class RootObject
{
    public int encoding_version { get; set; }
    public Root root { get; set; }
}
```

Then you use the `MemoryStream` and the `DataContractJsonSerializer` to Create an object of `RootObject` from that JSON.

```
MemoryStream stream1 = new MemoryStream();  
DataContractJsonSerializer ser = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(RootObject));  

stream1.Position = 0;  
RootObject rootObject = (RootObject)ser.ReadObject(stream1);
```

---

And yes, as Adriani6  mentiones - your JSON is invalid at this point:

```
"Data": {
            "_type": "p_model",
            "Class": ".key.Unsupported",
            "MType": ".TestMType",
            "Version": {
              "_type": "test__version",
              "Class": ".key.TestVersion",

            }
```

There is a `,` at the end wich is not allowed.

Comment: Thanks! but i am trying to fetch 'RollId' and 'MType' from "Data" can we pick only these two fields?

Comment: DataContractSerializer isn't a good choice. It's an old implementation only meant as a stop-gap measure way back when. They way it handles dates is incompatible with the defacto standard, ISO8601. The most popular deserializer is JSON.NET which is also used  in ASP.NET Web API and ASP.NET Core.

Comment: Ah okay, didn't know that. I'm not workint that much with JSON and when I do I use the `DataContractSerializer`. But good to know for the future!